# Initialize a Python Variable with json data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I have a very simple situation:

```
response = None

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

if response == None:
    response = results {
                       alternatives {
                                       transcript: ""
                                       confidence: 0.0
                                    }
                       language_code: None
                       }

print(response)
```

I want to initialize the response with an empty object if the client does not return anything.

How to do it? i.e. construct a json object in python.

Comment: what is a "json object"? JSON is a text format. Did you mean a dictionnary from a json?

Comment: @dgan yes, the dictionary from a json, so that i could access the elements inside it

Answer (score 1):

If I interpet you correctly, what you want to do is following:

```
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

if response is None:
    response = {'results':
                    {'alternatives': {'transcript': "", 'confidence': 0.0},
                     'language_code': None}
                }
print(response)
```

However since you mentionned reading a python object from json, here you go:

```
import json
result = json.loads("""
         {"a":42, "b":{"h":null}}
         """)
```

Note that the following part of your question:

```
                       alternatives {
                                       transcript: ""
                                       confidence: 0.0
                                    }
                       language_code: None
                       }
```

is not a valid json.